# How to change a PHP SESSION VARIABLE using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax

I am very new to PHP and just starting to learn AJAX.

I want to know if its possible to change a PHP SESSION VARIABLE using AJAX and how to do it... I tried to check on some examples but most of it are just displaying some values on the browser.

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

**`index.php`**:

```
<?php
 $_SESSION['test'] = 1;
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js" > </script>

<div>
 <?php echo "Before: " . $_SESSION['test']; ?>
 <input type="submit" value="CLICK" onclick="resetVar('<?php echo $_SESSION['test']; ?>')" />
 <?php echo "After: " . $_SESSION['test']; ?>
</div>
```

**`functions.js`**:

```
function resetVar(sessionVal) {
 sessionVal = null;

 var httpRequest;

 if(window.XMLHttpRequest)  httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 if(window.ActiveXObject) httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

 if(httpRequest.readyState == 4 && httpRequest.status == 200) {
  // I don't know what to put here...
 }

 httpRequest.open("get", "index.php?$_SESSION['test'] = " + sessionVal, true);
 httpRequest.send();
}
```

I know its terribly wrong and I need help to fix this. I want AJAX to do a similar **unset** the **$_SESSION['test']** variable when I hit the submit button. I want it to do someting like `unset($_SESSION['test'])`. Please help me with this...

Answer (score 2):

Practically speaking your script does nothing in many ways, here and there. Seems to me you don't understand the main and basic concepts of programming for the web.

Please read and understand the basics: http://www.google.com/search?q=how+php+works

Else there isn't a thing I can help with but doing the whole task for you.

Comment: Technically with slight modification, it could work if `register_globals` were enabled, but that's like chopping off both legs so your arm can work.